# DNS: Do i need to create a DNS entry to represent each of my web applications running in a same windows server under IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, dns, asp.net-core-webapi

## Updated the question:

Assume that i run several web applications in one windows server under IIS. As you know, for the several web applications to co-exist in IIS, i need to differentiate them using a hostname, ip address or port combinations. Assuming that i go with defining a hostname binding unique for each of the web applications, do i need to create a DNS entry for the hostnames to be resolved?

There are three different sites i host in IIS in the same windows server. I can not allocate different ip address to each of my dev sites so i chose to use unique host names for each of the sites thus

```
api-orders.dev
api-catalog.dev
api-products.dev

etc..
```

`api` - indicates it is a web api.

`orders | catalog | products` - indicate it is an application serving a business department.

`dev` - indicates it is my development site.

My organization has several domains such as usdev.org.com, us.org.com, uk.dtt.org.com and more like.

Assuming that my Dev servers are hosted in the usdev.org.com domain. I should be able to request my hypothetical sites from within and also outside of the usdev.org.com domain

right now, when i use the below urls, i am not able to hit the site within or outside the domain. Not even from the web server where the sites are hosted. I ask this question to several people and could not get a clear response.

DO i need to create DNS entries corresponding to the hostname IIS binding of each site in order to solve this issue?

```
api-orders.dev.computer-name.domain.com
api-catalog.dev.computer-name.domain.com
api-products.dev.computer-name.domain.com
```

What kind of setup i need to acheive this?

Comment: Do not use the `.dev` TLD, it exists globally, and has restrictions (HSTS preloading).

Comment: That's a good question for your network administrators, but not related to programming at all. IIS bindings are there to control what HTTP requests might come, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background but what kind of URLs you like and how to configure them are off-topic. BTW, DNS configuration is clearly needed, so forget about hosts file.

Comment: @LexLi I edited the question to remove some of the out of topic content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the website via your Active directory. I think you shouldn't include servername in your domain name.

Because in common AD DNS Forward Lookup Zone.
You should have a primary zone called **domain.com**. Your web server will displayed as a HOST(A) **Servername** and its FQDN will be **servername.domain.com**.
Then you could create a CNAME **api-orders.dev** and map it to your servername.domain.com. The FQDN should  be api-orders.dev.domain.com.

Finally you have to set the domain into IIS binding so that IIS can share 80 port for mutiple sites.
Since your cname api-orders.dev will not be considered as a seperate website, you have to input FQDN instead of CNAME.

If you want to access the website from internet, then you may need to purchase public domain from domain provider and map it to your server's public IP address.

Comment: this is how i interpret your answer. For machines provisioned by an organization, there already exists a DNS entry for an A record with a FQDN server-name.domain.com so in order for the custom hostnames to be resolved, a c-name record should be created. In my example, there might be 3 cname entries required pointing to the A record. is this unerstanding correct?

Comment: Yes. In this case, you need to create 3 cname entries and point them to your server's A record. Then you need to specify these  cname entries into your web app's binding host header. So IIS would know which requests should be requested by which app pool.